# What's the fastest way checking if two moving AABBs intersect?

Tags: collision-detection

I have two AABBs that are moving, what's the fastest way to check if they will intersect under a frame?

By moving I mean not just to check with the usual rectangle intersection method, I mean some kind of simple easy swept test that only returns a boolean, no hit time or anything else.

What I think is to simply do it like this:

[image: This]

But that Hexagon is quite complex and I don't know how to calculate an AABB - Polygon intersection, is there maybe an easier way?

Any programming language that you like the most, I can easily port it.

Thanks.

Comment: upvote for the colour of the squiggles.  No idea what you are talking about btw

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the problem if you think of the produced shape as the union of two rects (A's original position and A's final position) and a skewed rectangle (which is given by the movement).
I can't post images due to my reputation so I'll just leave a link to an image that explains what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnsLK.png

Then you have to evaluate if any of the following shapes collide with B:

- A's original position against B (AABB - AABB collision)
- A's final position against B (AABB - AABB collision again)
- The skewed rectangle against B (OBB collision)

For the last case you can use the separating axis theorem, which will work as the produced shape should always be convex.

If you're wondering which points should be used for the convex shape, I suggest using the ones that are adjacent to the point that matches the movement direction (ie. if the rectangle is moving up and left, pick the two points adjacent to the upper left point of the original position and the two points adjacent to the lower right of the final position) with special cases for orthogonal movement.